# How to solve $ay''+by'+cy=0$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good afternoon,
I was just wondering if someone can guide me through step by step to solve: $$ay''+by'+cy=0,\quad a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$$ 
Is the characteristic equation still valid? Why or why not? How would the final form of the solution look like?
thank you

Comment: What happens if the discriminant still has complex how happens to the final answer??

Comment: Moo thank you very much, then I have no other option but to keep them in complex. I thought they might be a chance to get out of the complex. What about using Laplace transformation, can it give you a smoother solution? 
Again I thank you sir for your help

Answer (score 1):

As usual,
assuming a solution of the form
$y = e^{ux}$,
we get
$0
=e^{ux}(au^2+bu+c)
$
so solutions exist whenever
$au^2+bu+c = 0
$.

The standard quadratic formula
suffices when the roots
are distinct.

When $b^2-4ac = 0$,
iirc, the solutions are
$e^{ux}$ and
$xe^{ux}$.

Nothing original here.

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

$$\text{a}\cdot y''(t)+\text{b}\cdot y'(t)+\text{C}\cdot y(t)=0$$

You can use Laplace transform:

$$\text{a}\cdot\left(\text{s}^2\text{Y}(\text{s})-\text{s}y(0)-y'(0)\right)+\text{b}\cdot\left(\text{s}\text{Y}(\text{s})-y(0)\right)+\text{C}\cdot\text{Y}(\text{s})=0$$

Solving for $\text{Y}(\text{s})$ gives us:

$$\text{Y}(\text{s})=\frac{\text{a}\cdot\text{s}y(0)+\text{a}\cdot y'(0)+\text{b}\cdot y(0)}{\text{a}\cdot\text{s}^2+\text{b}\cdot\text{s}+\text{C}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I was just wondering where is Moo solution because that was the one I was looking for. The LT solution helps but I was wondering what happens if the coefficient 'a' is complex would my solution sound different. That is all what I am asking for
Again I thank you gentlemen for your help.